# Flex 4, Button blinks when mouse over it

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I am building a flash player application (Flex 4) in IntelliJ IDEA. A button is positioned on top of a VideoDisplay area and the visibility is set to false. It becomes visible when the mouse is over the VideoDisplay area.

The problem is that the button blinks rapidly when the mouse is over it (it does not blink, when the mouse is over the VideoDispaly area, and not right over the button, though).

in .mxml:

```
 <mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" visible="true" width="237" height="188" click="simplePlay()"
                         mouseOver="videoOnHover()" mouseOut="videoHoverOut()"
                         playheadUpdate="videoDisplay_playheadUpdate()"
                         ready="videoDisplay_ready()"
                         rewind="videoDisplay.play()"
                         autoPlay="false"
                         live="true"
                         source="rtmp://cp114761.live.edgefcs.net:443/live/tpc-live_1@44263"/>
```

```
        <mx:Button id="pauseButton" name="pause" visible="false" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" click="simplePause()"
                   overSkin="@Embed(source='img/pause-hover.png')"
                   upSkin="@Embed(source='img/pause.png')"
                   downSkin="@Embed(source='img/pause-hover.png')" />
```

in CDATA[ section:

```
private function videoOnHover():void {
            pauseButton.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Would be very grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put VideoDisplay and Button in the group and handle rollOver rollOut on it.

```
 <s:Group rollOver="videoOnHover()" rollOut="videoHoverOut()">
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" visible="true" width="237" height="188"
                     autoPlay="false"
                     live="true"/>
    <mx:Button id="pauseButton" name="pause" visible="false"/>
</s:Group>
```